# Why tflearn model prediction and traning accuracy are different when executed on different systems?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard, tflearn

I am working on Tflearn DNN model.  After training the model on different systems the prediction behaves differently in both the systems even if it was trained on the same data.

So which properties while training the data results into this behaviour where the prediction result is different?

Comment: Are you running the same trained model, or different models trained on the same data and same hyper parameters?

Comment: @dm0_ I am basically training the model on same data on different systems but the prediction outcome is different.  So yes different models trained on same data and same hyper parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Models training starts from random initialization. Also there is usually additional randomness in batch selection.

All this makes models trained on the same data and with the same hyper parameters still a bit different.

**Edit**:

You can control TensorFlow random number generator using [`tf.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed). Please note that there a 2 levels of random seeds. You also may need to set state of numpy random number generator.

But I can't be sure that this will help. It depends on implementation details.

Comment: but in Tflearn case how can I remove additional randomness in batch selection and random initialization.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I will implement that and let you know if my problem resolves.